# Django - IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have this error in my `ClientSetupView` that happens when I `Save` my input that I have added into my fields.

Any suggestion would be grateful.

Here is the log error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.33.10:8000/podfunnel/clientsetup/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('producer',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'storages',
 'django_extensions',
 'randomslugfield',
 'adminsortable2',
 'crispy_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/fullcast_project/producer/views/pod_funnel.py" in post
  150.             client.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  700.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  728.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  812.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  851.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1064.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /podfunnel/clientsetup/
Exception Value: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (66, 2016-06-19 23:03:11.186763+00, 2016-06-19 23:03:11.186868+00, Wilfredo, Lopez, , Fulano, null).
```

And here is my `ClientSetupView` in my `pod_funnel.py` view:

```
class ClientSetupView(View):
form_class = ClientSetupForm
template_name = 'pod_funnel/forms.html'

# In the get we manage the request to get the form and prefill it if necessary
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # We need to check first if the current user has a client and podcast setup,
    # if so, prepopulate. Otherwise get empty form.
    initial_values = {}
    user = request.user

    if Client.objects.filter(user=user).exists():

        client = CLient.objects.filter(user=user).first()

        initial_values['first_name'] = client.first_name
        initial_values['last_name'] = client.last_name

        podcast = Podcast.objects.filter(client=client).first()
        request.session['client_id'] = client.id

        if podcast:
            initial_values['podcast_name'] = podcast.name
            # lets store podcast_id in session so we can retrieve it directly in post
            request.session['podcast_id'] = podcast.id

    form = self.form_class(initial=initial_values)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

# In the the post we manage updates to the data
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        # lets get the data
        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        podcast_name = form.cleaned_data.get('podcast_name')

        # First we see if we have a client_id in session, if so we retrieve and update
        # otherwise we create a new one.
        client_id = request.session.get('client_id', None)
        if client_id is not None:
            request.session.delete('client_id')
            client = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
        else:
            client = Client()
        client.first_name = first_name
        client.last_name = last_name
        client.company_name = podcast_name
        client.save()

        # Now we update or create the associated podcast.
        podcast_id = request.session.get('podcast_id', None)
        if podcast_id is not None:
            request.session.delete('podcast_id')
            podcast = Podcast.objects.get(id=podcast_id)
        else:
            podcast = Podcast()
        podcast.client = client
        podcast.name = podcast_name
        podcast.save()

        success, message_list = update_or_create_preset_for_podcast(podcast)

        # in any case we can continue with additional podcast setup, but we need
        # to attempt to create the preset one more time at some point before the
        # user can create the first productions.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('podfunnel:podcastsetup'))

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your post method provide:

```
    user = request.user

    if client_id is not None:
        request.session.delete('client_id')
        client = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
    else:
        client = Client.objects.create(user=user) # your user must not be empty
```